# Laravel 5.5 Validation mimes:apk doesn't work

Tags: php, android, validation, laravel-5, apk

I'm attempting to validate a file upload.  It can be many types of file including an vnd.android.package-archive (apk) file.  It is in the list of mimes types on this link https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types that the laravel docs refer to.  However if I test an `.apk` file it errors and is not recognising it as valid mime.

Here is the `rules` array my request file

```
return [
    'file' => [
        'max:' . config('medialibrary.max_digital_asset_file_size'),
        'mimes:' . config('medialibrary.digital_media_file_mime_types')
    ]
];
```

I set the mime types globaly in the medialibrary config file like this

```
'digital_media_file_mime_types' => 'doc,docx,xls,csv,txt,pdf,zip,jpeg,jpg,png,ppt,mov,mpeg,mp4,apk',
```

I have also tried like this

```
'digital_media_file_mime_types' => 'doc,docx,xls,csv,txt,pdf,zip,jpeg,jpg,png,ppt,mov,mpeg,mp4,vnd.android.package-archive',
```

I can upload pdf's and csv's and .zip's etc OK

Any clues would be handy.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured this out. when I put a `logger(request()->all())` at the top of the request rules array, the `file` came out like this

```
'file' => 
  Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::__set_state(array(
     'test' => false,
     'originalName' => 'QuickDrive.apk',
     'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.android.package-archive',
     'size' => 95585970,
     'error' => 0,
     'hashName' => NULL,
  )),
```

However, I managed to track down the method in the Laravel framework that validates mimes.  In the `vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php` class, there is a `validateMimes` method.  I put another logger at the bottom of that before the return to see what the "guessed" extension was for the file, and it came out as `jar` which when I looked that up, is a `application/java-archive` file type.  So Laravel is basically guessing what the file types are, and gets it wrong for .apk files.  So I added in `jar` to my list of acceptable mimes and it works fine.  Not brilliant perhaps but gets my passed this hurdle.